# In Winforms is it posible to catch the error in one place rather than in every try catch

Tags: c#

Is it possible to handle all the errors in one place rather than writing try{} catch{} for all the blocks.

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    logger.Error(ex.Message);
    ShowErrorMessage(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but that may not be what you actually want.  It means that the exception will unwind the stack up to the op of your application, and will not continue doing anything were you were at.

Answer (score 4):

You should generally handle exceptions as soon as possible unless you don't know how to handle them. For uncaught exceptions you can handle the [AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) and [Application.ThreadException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx) events. The `UnhandledException` event will fire if an exception is thrown somewhere in your code but you haven't handled it. From MSDN:

> [UnhandledException] provides notification of uncaught exceptions. It allows the
>   application to log information about the exception before the system
>   default handler reports the exception to the user and terminates the
>   application. If sufficient information about the state of the
>   application is available, other actions may be undertaken — such as
>   saving program data for later recovery. Caution is advised, because
>   program data can become corrupted when exceptions are not handled.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need to register a uncaught exception. This can be done in Project settings "View Application Events" It's called MyApplication_UnhandledException